# How to invoke "Turn Off Airplane Mode" notification

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

In many applications, such as the Mail app, if the device is in airplane mode a notification will pop up that says "Turn Off Airplane Mode or Use Wi-Fi to Access Data."

I thought that this would automatically be invoked if my app tries to access the internet, but it is not.  Is there a special method to do this, or if not how can I check if the device is in airplane mode and provide a link to Settings to disable it?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you add the `UIRequiresPersistentWifi` key to your `Info.plist` and set it to `YES`, then if you're in Airplane mode, you'll get the standard "Turn Off Airplane Mode..." popup on launch.

Comment: As of 2016, UIRequiresPersistentWifi has changed to "Application uses Wi-Fi" in the app settings Info section.

Answer (score 5):

I test in my app. I find it changed. "UIRequiresPersistentWifi" => "Application uses Wi-Fi".
I hope it will help somebody.

[image: xCode Target Properties]

Comment: As of 2016 this seems to be the most up-to-date answer here.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the apple's reachablity framework when you app launches to check for network connectivity. Check this out

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html

I have a wrapper class for reachbiltiy APIs to make it simpler to use. (ASIHTTPRequest has one as well).

https://github.com/daltoniam/GPHTTPRequest

see the GPReachablity class for checking for connectivity. As far as a dialog prompt, not sure there is a way to push to the settings app. Any questions let me know.

Comment: There are cases when there is reception but no internet connectivity and it will be false positive as an airplane mode. If you are developing NOT for Apple's market then you can use the private API: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31583945/4260691 to get the signal strength and now when an event is fired you can check for the signal strength in the NotReachable case. If the signal strength is zero then it is a 100% airplane mode.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the standard *Turn Off Airplane Mode or Use Wi-Fi to Access Data [settings | ok]*

1. Add a new property in your `info.plist` by clicking the `+` sign at the top.
2. The new property is called `UIRequiresPersistentWiFi` (this is similar to postings above, but needs to be exact otherwise it doesn't register)
3. Change type from `String` to `Boolean`
4. Change value from `NO` to `YES`
5. Clean and rebuild your app

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](http://blogs.oreilly.com/iphone/2009/01/bring-airplane-mode-control-ba.html). Apparently, `Airport control was moved by Apple into a separate framework`

It seems there is no standard way to notify the user to turn airplane mode back on. As you mentioned, this obviously isn't very elegant, so I assume apple deleted this feature.

Comment: That's from 2009 and uses all kinds of backdoors. I suspect the real answer is "No way". I've had a bug in on this for like 3 years now - I think Apple dupped it.

Comment: Well I mean I think this still works, even though it isn't very elegant.