# Calculating IOS signal strength using CTGetSignalStrength()

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, ios8

I have begun developing a non-Apple store app for iOS 8.3 that measures and returns the Received Signal Strength Indicator (RSSI) value in dB. I got access to a git repository for an Xcode project named VAFieldTest that uses the Core Telephony framework in order to get access to information such as cell ID, serving mnc, RSSI, etc. However, the build of the project fails and returns the following error:

```
    Ld /Users/rajesh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VAFieldTest-dmyrokwehbyuqcauvwpiouivlnqy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/VAFieldTest.app/VAFieldTest normal i386
    cd /Users/rajesh/Documents/VAFieldTest
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=4.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.4.sdk -L/Users/rajesh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VAFieldTest-dmyrokwehbyuqcauvwpiouivlnqy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/rajesh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VAFieldTest-dmyrokwehbyuqcauvwpiouivlnqy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.4.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks -filelist /Users/rajesh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VAFieldTest-dmyrokwehbyuqcauvwpiouivlnqy/Build/Intermediates/VAFieldTest.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/VAFieldTest.build/Objects-normal/i386/VAFieldTest.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=4.0 -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreTelephony -weak_framework VoiceServices -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/rajesh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VAFieldTest-dmyrokwehbyuqcauvwpiouivlnqy/Build/Intermediates/VAFieldTest.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/VAFieldTest.build/Objects-normal/i386/VAFieldTest_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/rajesh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VAFieldTest-dmyrokwehbyuqcauvwpiouivlnqy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/VAFieldTest.app/VAFieldTest

ld: -pie can only be used when targeting iOS 4.2 or later
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

At first I thought it was due to the linking of the new library but upon inspection, the build dependencies have already been included and it didn't help. I thought of calling the Core Telephony methods myself but the official documentation lists no methods for accessing these core functions in iOS 8.3. The listed methods are available at the developers documentation library and don't contain the required methods.

How do I get the RSSI values in iOS 8.3? Im using Xcode 6.4 beta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is no longer possible, apparently as a side-effect to patching a vulnerability. [Get CellID, LAC, ... on iOS 8.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29533059/get-cellid-lac-on-ios-8-3)

Comment: Wanted to develop an app that stores the user locations and his signal strength at regular time steps and use it for some statistical analysis. Unfortunately, seems to be the dead end. Looks a bit complicated in Android too.... Thnx

Answer (score 10):

You can get signal strength using this:

```
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
NSArray *subviews = [[[app valueForKey:@"statusBar"] valueForKey:@"foregroundView"] subviews];
NSString *dataNetworkItemView = nil;

for (id subview in subviews) {
    if([subview isKindOfClass:[NSClassFromString(@"UIStatusBarSignalStrengthItemView") class]]) {
        dataNetworkItemView = subview;
        break;
    }
}

int signalStrength = [[dataNetworkItemView valueForKey:@"signalStrengthRaw"] intValue];

NSLog(@"signal %d", signalStrength);
```

Comment: Wow. that's.. clever.

Comment: Replace "UIStatusBarSignalStrengthItemView" with "UIStatusBarDataNetworkItemView" and "signalStrengthRaw" with "wifiStrengthBars". Unfortunately "wifiStrengthRaw" always return 0.

Comment: awsome thank's, however, this is not working for background modes, because the bar isn't linked to the app i think...

Comment: Yes i know. But still it's nice solution and can work for most cases. :)

Comment: looks great - however, wouldn't this count as using private API and thus be rejected?

Comment: Yes it will be rejected, because it uses private variable.

Comment: @MateuszMirkowski how did you find this private API ?

Comment: wifiStrengthRaw returns a negative number when running on a device. Simulator will always return 0.

Comment: And I suspect that wifiStrengthRaw is the RSSI value in hex, and stringForRSSI will give the value in decimal

Comment: This method does not work background. Any idea anybody how can we get the cellular signal strength when the app is in background.